# Django dateutil parse is changing the date to today's date

Tags: django, python-dateutil

I am trying to use Django dateutil.pareser.parse() to change the date '2016:09:24 17:08:45' to '2016-09-24 17:08:45'. But when I use the following code:

```
the_timestamp = self.request.query_params.get('timestamp',0) # = '2016:09:24 17:08:45'
the_parsed_timestamp = dateutil.parser.parse(the_timestamp)
```

I get the result the_parsed_timestamp = '2016-10-16 17:08:45'. 2016-10-16 is today's date.

Why is dateutil.parser.parse replacing the date with today's date (and leaving the time part alone)?

Comment: Do you know that it's always in the format "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:S"? If so, don't use `dateutil.parser`, use `datetime.strptime`. That said, this seems like a bug, you should report it on [dateutil's issue tracker](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues) - even if that format is not supported it shouldn't be silently failing.

Comment: By the way, I suspect that what is happening is that it's interpreting `2016:09:24` as `%H:%M:%S`, and the way `dateutil` works, if you give it 2 HMS triplets in a row, the second one will overwrite the first one. If you pass `2016:09:24` by itself to the parser, it will give an error because "2016" is too big of an hour, so you're effectively just passing this "17:08:45"

Comment: Oh ok, so parse is not clever enough for this format? My problem is that I am not sure what format the datetime is going to come in as so I was hoping I could use a clever utility like dateutil parse to sort this out for me. Is there an alernative to dateutil?

Comment: @p I have tried strptime as you suggest but get error: ValueError: time data '2016:09:24 17:09:18' does not match format '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:S' Ah ok I see the typo now :)

Comment: I think it's just that it's a bug in dateutil. You can try `dateparser`, but I am not so familiar with its general capabilities. It's very hard to parse anything that could ever be considered a date properly, so non-standard formats generally don't get supported by these sorts of things and you end up just needing to special-case.

Comment: Thanks @Paul I need to look deeper into this but the strptime will get around the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong date format. It should be:

```
2016-09-24
```

not

```
2016:09:24
```

Comment: Yes I know. The date coming in is in the format 2016:09:24 I am trying to use the dateutil parse function to convert it to the correct format. It seems to do this ok except for changing the date!

Comment: @BillNoble Is the format consistent? Maybe you can just use `datetime.datetime.strptime('2016:09:24 17:08:45', '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')` instead.

Comment: That works for this particular case but the date format is not consistent